# tensorflow reinitializable iterator questions

Tags: tensorflow

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(64)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_x, test_y))
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(1000)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types,
                                       train_dataset.output_shapes)

next_element_x, next_element_y = iterator.get_next()

training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
testing_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(test_dataset)

logits = DenseNet(x=next_element_x, nb_blocks=nb_block, filters=growth_k, training=training_flag).model
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=next_element_y, logits=logits))

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(next_element_y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

I'm trying to use the input pipeline to improve the performance of the code. And I use the re-initializable iterator to implement it.

In my code, the `next_element_y` generated by `iterator.get_next()` is used twice in each iteration (both cost and correct_prediction).
Therefore, I have 782 iterations/epoch, and it gets Out Of Range error after 391 iterations.

How to use the `next_element_y` twice without triggering the iterator extra one more time in one iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `initializable_iterator`

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y))
train_dataset = ds_train.shuffle().repeat() #repeat to control epochs and out of range error
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(64)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_x, test_y))
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(1000)

train_iterator = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
test_iterator = test_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
    sess.run(test_iterator.initializer)
    for i in steps:
        next_element = sess.run(train_iterator.get_next())
```

Difference is that you define `next_element` once and then use. For example:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
        sess.run(test_iterator.initializer)
        for i in steps:
            print(sess.run(train_iterator.get_next())) #This will print 1st element in dataset
            print(sess.run(train_iterator.get_next())) #This will print next element in dataset

with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
            sess.run(test_iterator.initializer)
            for i in steps:
                next_element = sess.run(train_iterator.get_next())) 
                print(next_element) #This will print 1st element in dataset
                print(next_element) #And this will print 1st element
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way

```
iterator_t = ds_t.make_initializable_iterator()
iterator_v = ds_v.make_initializable_iterator()

iterator_handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[], name="iterator_handle")
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(iterator_handle, 
                                               iterator_t.output_types,
                                               iterator_t.output_shapes)

def get_next_item():
  # sometimes items need casting
  next_elem = iterator.get_next(name="next_element")
  x, y = tf.cast(next_elem[0], tf.float32), next_elem[1]
  return x, y  

def old_data():
        # just forward the existing batch
        return inputs, target

is_keep_previous = tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.constant(False),shape=[], name="keep_previous_flag")

inputs, target =  tf.cond(is_keep_previous, old_data, new_data)

with tf.Session() as sess:
 sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer()])        
 handle_t = sess.run(iterator_t.string_handle())
 handle_v = sess.run(iterator_v.string_handle())
 # Run data iterator initialisation
 sess.run(iterator_t.initializer)
 sess.run(iterator_v.initializer)
 while True:
   try:
     inputs_, target_ = sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle: handle_t, is_keep_previous:False})
     print(inputs_, target_)
     inputs_, target_ = sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle: handle_t, is_keep_previous:True})
     print(inputs_, target_)
     inputs_, target_ = sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle: handle_v})
     print(inputs_, target_)
   except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
     # now we know we run out of elements in the validationiterator
     break
```

Comment: Hi! This could be very useful for me, but I can't reproduce your idea. I assume `new_data` is supposed to be `get_next_item()`? And where would you define `inputs, target` for the first time? That code looks like it'd complain about referring to uninitialised variables inside the `old_data()` method.

Comment: I looked at the old code (not sure it that was the version I based my answer on) and it looks like `new_data` is a function that returns new batch 
```
def new_data():
    # run the data layer to generate a new batch
    next_inputs, next_target = get_next_item()
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(inputs, next_inputs), tf.assign(target, next_target)]):
        return tf.identity(inputs), tf.identity(target)
```

and `inputs` and `target` are defined before everything as

Comment: ```
inputs = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[batch_size,3]), dtype=tf.float32, name="inputs", trainable=False, use_resource=True)
target = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[batch_size], dtype=tf.int32), dtype=tf.int32, name="target", trainable=False
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin! I have solved my problem in another way, but I'm sure this will be useful for other people who find this question :)